# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

This is my code to the 1st migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDailyStandupMomTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('project_daily_standup_moms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->date('date');
            $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('edited_by_user')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('edited_by_user')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->integer('added_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('added_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('project_daily_standup_moms');
    }
}
```

and this is the code I have for the 2nd one

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDailyStandupMomListTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('project_daily_standup_mom_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('mom_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('mom_id')->references('id')->on('project_daily_standup_mom')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');;
            $table->text('filled_for');
            $table->text('remark')->nullable();
            $table->text('status');
            $table->text('logged_time')->nullable();
            $table->text('estimation')->nullable();
            $table->text('new_blocker_description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('new_blocker_assign_to')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('new_blocker_assign_to')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('project_daily_standup_mom_lists');
    }
}
```

It is giving me the following error

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ticktalk_s`.`proje  
  ct_daily_standup_mom_lists` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrec  
  tly formed") (SQL: alter table `project_daily_standup_mom_lists` add constr  
  aint `project_daily_standup_mom_lists_mom_id_foreign` foreign key (`mom_id`  
  ) references `project_daily_standup_mom` (`id`) on delete set null on updat  
  e cascade)
```

I have looked into similar questions but I just could not find an answer for this one.
I have checked the order of the migrations, the type of the foreign key and everything seems all right.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe create the table first and add another migration that adds the foreignkey to itself?

Comment: Do you really need to set the column type for foreigne keys beforehand, like in `$table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();`?

Comment: @brombeer , tried that, didn't work. same error. and yea, I guess I can combine the types to the second line but it is not making any defference.

Comment: `id()` doesn't create an unsigned integer, it creates an unsigned Big integer via `bigIncrements()` which is `unsignedBigInteger(..., true)`

Answer (score 0):

changed
`$table->integer('mom_id')->nullable();`
to
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('mom_id')->nullable();`
in the second migration and it worked.

I really hope this helps someone.